How to add a link to Id property using MudBlazor
<MudDataGrid Items="@Data">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Id"/>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Title" Title="Title"/>
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>

How to add a link to Id property using MudBlazor?

What do you mean link? Question needs more details.

You could use TemplateColum to make a custom column for Id
<MudDataGrid Items="@Data">
    <Columns>
       
        <TemplateColumn >
            <HeaderTemplate>Id</HeaderTemplate>
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudLink Href="@($"/otherpage/{@context.Item.Id}")">@context.Item.Id</MudLink>
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>

        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Title" Title="Title" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>


@code{
    List<Message> Data { get; set; } = new List<Message>
    {
        new Message{Id=1,Title="title1"},
        new Message{Id=2,Title="title2"}
    };
    public class Message
    {
        public int Id{ get; set;}
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}

